# python pygame physics rectange - circle collision

Tags: python, pygame, physics

Again this question is on PyParticles4.
[Link to last question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137475/python-ball-physics-simulation)

Comment if unclear...

I am working on a Shooter game, much like [this](http://www.gamenet.com/game/Shooting-Games-Avalon-Siege/), but on a flat land with a wall that varies it's height on every turn(something for fun in the game) and with 2 players,each with a cannon that can move some distance (there's a limit, and they can't move beyond a certain amount from their start position) on each turn(the player decides if he wishes to move).

My code so far(for the Bullet and Shooter)

```
class Bullet(PyParticles.Particle):
    def hit(self,shooterlist):
        for shoot in shooterlist:
            #confusion
            dist = math.hypot(dx,dy)
    # other funcs to added
class Shooter:
    def __init__(self,pos,size):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos,size)
    # other funcs to added
```

### My Problems

Collision of the bullet with the Shooter. Any Ideas on how to know when the bullet collides with the rect?
I have been advised by someone to look at all the points on the edge of the rect, and see if it is within the circle but it seems to be very slow.
I think something faster would be better..
..
..
**Update:**
The circle can have a rect around it, which if collides with the rect, I now know when the rect is close to the circle, maybe even touching it.. How do i move forward??(Thx to PygameNerd)

Comment: "very slow" is relative. Premature optimization can cripple a project.

Comment: Have you checked out [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search-new?q=[python]+circle+collision)?

Comment: @PaulC The final fps of the game could be slower if the wall is longer or the Perimeter of the rect is big.....

Comment: @martineau Not One I see has rect-circle collision

Comment: If it does slow down, and you profiled it, you can look into quadtrees. But I think it's overkill for your game.

Comment: @monkey what are quad-trees???

Comment: Check out [1] http://www.pygame.org/project-Quadtree+test-1691-.html [2] http://devmag.org.za/2011/02/23/quadtrees-implementation/

Comment: @monkey I don't get how to implement it??

Comment: I'm saying don't use it for now, just note for later to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by your question, but I thingk that you need the `colliderect` function.

```
rect.colliderect(rect): Return bool
```

Put this in the code somewhere, and if it returns true, have the ball explode.

Comment: @paddila I know.  You need to use the circle's rect, not the circle itsself.

Answer (score 1):

You can run another test every time `colliderect` returns true.  There are a few options for what that test can be.  One is similar to the advice you already received but with the wall and circle switched.  Check the points on the circumference of the circle to see if one of them collides with the wall using [`Rect.collidepoint`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.collidepoint).  In pygame, you can get a list of circumference points by creating a [`Mask`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) from the circle surface and running [`Mask.outline`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#Mask.outline).  You probably won't need every point, so you could get just every Nth point.  In fact, you may only need the midpoints of the edges of the circle's rect, which you can get from the `Rect` object itself.

You're asking for precise collision, and that would give you pixel perfect collision detection between a circle and a rectangle.  You may not need it in your game, though, so I suggest trying with just `colliderect` first.  If you're interested in collision detection in pygame in general, there are a lot of options that are directly implemented in or based on functions described in the `Mask` and `Sprite` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rect.collidepoint with the center of the circle but make rect bigger

```
collide_rect = Rect(x - p.radius,y - p.radius,w + 2 * p.radius,h + 2 * p.radius)
if collide_rect.collide_point(p.pos):
    # Collision Resolution
```