# python - Implementation of friction(Spin) with rotation of circle (2-D)

Tags: python, pygame, physics, geometry

This is another question on [PyParticles4.py](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/sites/files/peter/PyParticles4.txt)(4th version).

**The Particle Class**
Circular 2d objects with radius,mass,velocity,location

I was thinking of making a version of [this game](http://www.foddy.net/cricket.swf) on python, using pygame and PyParticles. The only thing I am puzzled about is the friction of the balls to the surface(pitch) below, when it bounces.

So, Any ideas on that??
Also, Is it possible to show rotation of a ball(without making a new class) and change it realistically(application of a force) so the ball 'spins'(cricket term)??

Comment: What have you tried? Good questions for StackOverflow are related to code issues you're having. If you're just getting started, try something first, then ask about the issues you run into!

Comment: @Blckknght The issue is that I have no ideaI(also can't think of one) how to apply friction to the particle(circular object) also changed the question to be clearer

Comment: Are you writing your own physics, or using a physics engine?

Comment: @monkey Actually it is the extension of the Particle class as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137475/python-ball-physics-simulation.. Same Module..

Comment: Do you mean the "friction" when the ball bounces, or when it rolls?

Comment: @beta When the ball bounces, it should spin..

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming the ball is hitting a non-moving object(as in the game)**

You can use the rotation speed of the ball, then multiply that with the friction constants of the ball and the surface it contacts, then another constant(i)(for making it usable).
That is:

```
 x = ball.rpm * ball.friction * pitch.friction * i  
 ball.angle += x
```

Then tweak `i`and the `*.friction` constants till you get the required result.

Comment: In what range should the `*.friction` constants be? more than 1, less than it??         
Also, The ball's rpm should change after bouncing..

Comment: Ok.. But you don't have any idea on what to do??